# cannot change height of a svg group element with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

```
<svg>
<!--SOME SVG CODE HERE-->
<g id="bg"> <!--More svg code-->
</g>

</svg>

<!--Imports-->
<script src="script.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="st.css">
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#bg{
    height:100%;
}
```

When i use javascript to change the height:

```
document.getElementById("bg").style.height = "500px"
```

nothing happens, and, when i try to print the height in screen, it's returns nothing:

```
alert(document.getElementById("bg").style.height)
```

what can i do to change the height with javascript.

Comment: <g> elements do not have width or height properties i.e. you can set them but they will be ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you need to give a width and a height to an element inside an svg element you have to use a `<symbol>` with a `viewBox` instead of a `group`. Next you have to use the `<symbol>`and you can give a width and a height to the `<use>` element

```css
svg{border:solid}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 100" width="300">
  <symbol id="c" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
    <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="5"/>
  </symbol>
  
  <use xlink:href="#c" x="10" y="10" width="40" height="40" />
</svg>
```